# Comparing to a null string in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for a way to compare a string to a null string the optimal way.

If I do

```
IF(str1 <> str2) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Strings are not equal');
END IF;
```

This gets ignored if str1 is NULL.

I know I can set a null string to something before comparing to make it work

```
str1 := NVL(str1, 'Empty');
IF(str1 <> str2) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Strings are not equal');
END IF;
```

And that works but I wanted to see if there is a better way to handle null string comparisons

Comment: Can `str1` be null too? What do you want the result to be if both strings are null - should they be considered equal? Depending on your answer, either `lnnvl` or `decode` (but not in the way you attempted) may be the simplest/most efficient answer. Both are proprietary to Oracle Database (not available in SQL Server, MySQL etc.) - is that OK?

Comment: Note also that your use of DECODE is syntactically incorrect - did you test that code before posting it? If so, it resulted in an error - perhaps that should have been mentioned. If you didn't try it before posting - why not?

Comment: @mathguy, sorry, I put in DECODE when it was actually NVL

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether the string you must compare (`str1`) may be null; nor what the result of the comparison should be if either string is null.

It very rarely (if ever) makes sense to consider a non-null string equal to null. Sometimes it does make sense to consider two null strings as equal (if you think of them as "empty strings" - idiotically, Oracle doesn't make the distinction, mandated by the SQL Standard, between the SQL concept of null, on the one hand, and the empty string concept on the other hand).

The condition below:

```
str1 = str2
```

returns TRUE if both strings are non-null and they are equal; it returns FALSE if both strings are non-null and they are different; and it returns UNKNOWN if at least one string is null.

The [LNNVL operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/LNNVL.html) (which takes a condition as its argument) returns FALSE when its argument is TRUE and it returns TRUE when its argument is either FALSE or UNKNOWN. So, the condition

```
 lnnvl(str1 = str2)
```

returns FALSE when the strings are both non-null and equal, and TRUE in all other cases. If you must consider two null strings as "not equal", then this is the condition you need in your code.

If, on the other hand, you must view two null strings as equal, you can use

```
decode(str1, str2, 0) is not null
```

In the case above, [DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DECODE.html) returns 0 if `str1` and `str2` are both non-null and equal, and **also** when they are both null. (This is why DECODE is often used in exactly this kind of situation). It returns the default (which I didn't specify, so the function will return the "default" default value, which is NULL) in the remaining cases. DECODE will return non-NULL when `str1` and `str2` are "the same" - either as equal, non-null strings, or as **both** null.

Of course, the DECODE condition can also be written as

```
decode(str1, str2, 0) = 0
```

or even

```
decode(str1, str2, 0, 1) = 0
```

to make it more explicit. Some people (not me!) may prefer it that way.

Comment: I really like that DECODE technique. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

If either `str1` or `str2` can be `NULL` then you can use:

```sql
IF    str1 <> str2
   OR str1 IS NULL AND str2 IS NOT NULL
   OR str1 IS NOT NULL AND str2 IS NULL
THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Strings are not equal');
END IF;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=afa77feac4c8dbbe4ec8637efa66c118)*

Answer (score 0):

What if `str2` literally is `'Empty'`? `nvl(str1, 'Empty');` (which is what you mean by `DECODE(str1, 'Empty')` I assume (`decode()` needs at least three parameters so your original expression would fail)) will give you a false negative. Just use `IS NULL`.

```
IF str1 <> str2
    OR str1 IS NULL
     OR str2 IS NULL THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Strings are not equal');
END IF;
```

Comment: No, `decode(str1, 'Empty')` will not give a false negative. It will give an error, since that expression is incorrect (`decode` must have at least three arguments).

Comment: @mathguy: Right, that was "selective reading" on my part...